# Sharepoint project site: notes field not synchronized from MS Project

Tags: sharepoint-online, tasks, ms-project

I noticed when synchronizing projects from MS Project that the Notes field does not appear to be synchronized and is not an option to display on the Sharepoint project tasks page.  Am I missing something, or is this something that will have to be custom added?

Thank you!